# User Input with Python on Anaconda?

Tags: python-2.7, ide, anaconda, spyder

I installed Anaconda (python version 2.7) with Spyder on my Windows 8.1 machine.  I'm taking some tutorials and would like to write a short program that I can run from Spyder - it should take user input and print it.  Literally something like:

var = raw_input()

print(var)

But I can't do this from a Spyder, and Python doesn't seem to have much for this in IDEs.

After some searching I found this: http://bugs.python.org/issue5680

Will this let me run the script out of Spyder?  If so, what is the correct way to install it?

Thanks!

Comment: How does a bug involving being able to set command-line arguments for a script run in IDLE relate to your problem?

Comment: Well, my problem is that I'd like to be able to ask for user inputs when I run the program out of the IDLE.  Doesn't the link go to a patch that does this?  As it currently stands, I have to change into the right directory in DOS and run the program.  Not terrible, but not what I want.

Comment: no, the patch does not do that. You can already ask for user input in IDLE quite easily, just as demonstrated in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand - how is this demonstrated in my question?  Because I don't know how to do this.  The lines of code in my question don't run when I run the program in Spyder.

Comment: What's the error you get?  It may be that Spyder is running your code in the same process space as itself, or has some problem doing I/O correctly to the sub-process.  I think most other Python IDEs would support this...

Answer (score 1):

Got it.  Python 3.4 uses input().  raw_input() is from 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Spyder doesn't support `raw_input`. You may need to run your script using just `python`.